# Risk in utilizing same list for two different conditional scenario inside Apex trigger

Tags: apex, list, trigger, dmlexception, size

**`Obj11`** is parent of **`Obj1`**.

If `Obj11.Lock = "Lock ALL"` -> Update all child records **`Obj1`**, with `Obj1.Lock= true;`

If `Obj11.Lock = "Unlock ALL"` -> Update all child records **`Obj1`**, with `Obj1.Lock= false;`

I have this following trigger on Obj11 to do so:

```
trigger TPI_Lock_All_MCCP on MC_Cycle_vod__c(after insert, after update) {
    Set < Id > Lock_Ids = new Set < Id > ();
    Set < Id > Unlock_Ids = new Set < Id > ();
    for (MC_Cycle_vod__c mc: trigger.new) {
        if (mc.TPI_Lock_All__c == 'Lock All MCCP')
            Lock_Ids.add(mc.Id);
        else if (mc.TPI_Lock_All__c == 'Unlock All MCCP')
            Unlock_Ids.add(mc.Id);
    }
    List < MC_Cycle_Plan_vod__c > MCCPupd = new List < MC_Cycle_Plan_vod__c > ();
    for (MC_Cycle_Plan_vod__c mccp: [Select Id, Lock_vod__c, Goal_Edit_Status_vod__c from MC_Cycle_Plan_vod__c where Cycle_vod__c in: Lock_Ids]) {
        mccp.Lock_vod__c = true;
        MCCPupd.add(mccp);
    }
    for (MC_Cycle_Plan_vod__c mccp: [Select Id, Lock_vod__c, Goal_Edit_Status_vod__c from MC_Cycle_Plan_vod__c where Cycle_vod__c in: Unlock_Ids]) {
        mccp.Lock_vod__c = false;
        mccp.Goal_Edit_Status_vod__c = 'New_vod';
        MCCPupd.add(mccp);
    }
    if (MCCPupd.size() > 0)
        update MCCPupd;
}
```

but here I've used the same List **`MCCPupd`** to populate child records **`Obj1`** for both the conditions Lock All and Unlock All.
Is there any risk in this approach, or I should keep  two different **`List<Obj1>`** and update the same after checking **`list.size()>0`** ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is fine.

```
for(MC_Cycle_Plan_vod__c mccp : [Select Id,Lock_vod__c,Goal_Edit_Status_vod__c from 
 MC_Cycle_Plan_vod__c where Cycle_vod__c in : Lock_Ids]){
```

The above query creates one list of records which you add to `MCCPupd`. The below query creates an entirely different list which you also add to it:

```
for(MC_Cycle_Plan_vod__c mccp : [Select Id,Lock_vod__c,Goal_Edit_Status_vod__c from 
 MC_Cycle_Plan_vod__c where Cycle_vod__c in : Unlock_Ids]){
```

It's always good practice to combine your DML when possible. So putting it all into:

```
if(MCCPupd.size()>0) update MCCPupd;
```

isn't a problem. I'll add that if you're going to make a check, it's preferable to use `isEmpty()` over `size()`. Neither should be necessary. If there are no records to update, you won't get a runtime error.